# POST Message for uploading large file To Google Drive without Google Driver UI

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

My understanding is that to upload a large file to Google Drive from my own app using version 2 of the API, I should be sending a message like below. Unfortunately, I do not know how to achieve this format for the multipart message using Python. Does anyone have example Python code that could get me going in the right direction?

Thanks,
Chris

---

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart

Authorization: Bearer <Access token>
Content-Length: <length>
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="<a base64 encoded guid>"

--<a base64 encoded guid>
Content-Type: application/json

{"title": "test.jpg", "mimeType":"image/jpeg", "parents":[]}
--<a base64 encoded guid>
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<base64 encoded binary data>
--<a base64 encoded guid>--
```

Answer (score 4):

The Google Drive API's reference guide contains code snippet in many languages including Python for all of the API endpoints.

For your use-case, the [drive.files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) endpoint has the answer:

```
from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
# ...

def insert_file(service, title, description, parent_id, mime_type, filename):
  """Insert new file.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    title: Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
    description: Description of the file to insert.
    parent_id: Parent folder's ID.
    mime_type: MIME type of the file to insert.
    filename: Filename of the file to insert.
  Returns:
    Inserted file metadata if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
  body = {
    'title': title,
    'description': description,
    'mimeType': mime_type
  }
  # Set the parent folder.
  if parent_id:
    body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]

  try:
    file = service.files().insert(
        body=body,
        media_body=media_body).execute()

    return file
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occured: %s' % error
    return None
```

Comment: I am familiar with this code, and have tried using it before. When I try using it, I specify a filename like "test.jpeg", and get an error saying "test.jpeg" cannot be found. What am I supposed to do with filename? Is that the name of the file uploaded? Or the name I want to be once uploaded? It was also my understanding that unless you used multipart POST, you had to make two calls to the API, one to tell it what you are going to post, and the second to post the actual data. This code you have posted does not create a multipart POST as I am looking for and describe in the question.

Comment: The filename is the name of the file in the hard drive you want to read from; if reading from memory, you can use other MediaUPload type. To do a multipart request, simply set `resumable` to `False`.

Comment: Thanks Alain, but how do I get the name of the file the user uploaded from a form?

Comment: If upload a new file from a web form that doesn't require back-end logic, you can use the [Picker API](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open#open_and_upload_files_using_the_google_picker) instead which is much easier. Otherwise, since you are getting the blob from memory (not a hard drive), you should use the [MediaInMemoryUpload](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/apiclient/http.py#408) class instead.

Comment: I would like to do this without the picker, but still choosing the file from local hard drive. Is that possible? I am familiar with and using MediaInMemoryUpload for files I create inside my app.

Comment: To get the file from your hardrive, simply pass in the full path as the `filename` argument. `MediaFileUpload` will open this file and send the content to the Drive API.

Comment: how do you get the full path to the file? Why would you not just access the file that has been posted with <input type="file" name="file">

Comment: Where is the file posted? Are you reading the posted file from a request handler in your Python code? If this is the case, the file is not on the hard drive but in memory, so you should use MediaInMemoryUpload. If you are reading a file from the hard drive (you know the full path to the file), then it makes sense to use MediaFileUpload. Those 2 classes serve different purposes.

Comment: It doesn't look like I can get the full path for a file on the hard drive, so I'll switch to use MediaInMemoryUpload instead. Can you give me help on the request handler for a POST and getting the data for MediaInMemoryUplaod?

Answer (score 2):

I found answer elsewhere, this Python code produces the message shown in the question.

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart'

boundary = base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes)
parts = []
parts.append('--' + boundary)
parts.append('Content-Type: application/json')
parts.append('')
parts.append(json.dumps({
    'title': name,
    'mimeType': 'image/jpeg',
    'parents': [{
        'kind': 'drive#file',
        'id': folderId
        }] if folderId else []
    }))
parts.append('--' + boundary)
parts.append('Content-Type: image/jpeg')
parts.append('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64')
parts.append('')
parts.append(base64.b64encode(content))
parts.append('--' + boundary + '--')
parts.append('')
body = '\r\n'.join(parts)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="%s"' % boundary,
    'Content-Length': str(len(body)),
    'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token
    }
response = urlfetch.fetch(url, payload=body, method='POST', headers=headers)
assert response.status_code == 200, '%s - %s' % (response.status_code, response.content)
r = json.loads(response.content)
```